# Can't access EKS api server endpoint within VPC when private access is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

I have set up EKS cluser with "private access" enabled and set up one instance in the same VPC to communicate with EKS. The issue is if I enable to the "public access", I can access the api endpoint. But if I disable the public access and enable the private access, I can't access api endpoints.

When private access is enabled:

```
kubectl get svc
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup randomstring.region.eks.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
```

When public access is enabled:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   172.20.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   57m
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to enable `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` for my VPC.

When enabling the private access of a cluster, EKS creates a private hosted zone and associates with the same VPC. It is managed by AWS itself and you can't view it in your aws account. So, this private hosted zone to work properly, your VPC must have `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` set to `true`.

Note: Wait for a while for changes to be reflected(about 5 minutes).